# Proving that if |domain (f)|= |codomain (f)| where f:A→B is surjective, it will be injective too

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I thought about going to prove this by contradiction.
Assume that the domain and the codomain are finite.

Assuming for contradiction that if f(a)=f(b);a≠b;a,b∈A

Because of |A|=|B|, A and B are finite, there exists e∈B for which there does not exist d∈A: f(d)=e

Therefore f is not surjective which leads us to the contradiction. So f must be injective too.

**The issue is that I am not sure if this proof is correct formulated as I am a beginner. So I would like to see opinions or ways about how can I fix this, thanks.**

Comment: There's a fairly major assumption missing from the question: it's important that both the domain and the codomain are *finite*, otherwise it's false (consider the function from the integers to the naturals sending every $x$ to $2x$, for example: how would your proof break down here? If it's not clear, change your proof until it is)

Comment: I have edited, is it now a proper proof @user3482749?

Comment: Notice that adding that didn't actually change your proof in any way: you haven't used the finiteness anywhere, or rather you haven't said where you're using it. Which step in your proof uses the finiteness?

Comment: I mentioned that A and B are finite now @user3482749